# Multiple <HTML> tags in a single page

Tags: javascript, php

I am fairly new to PHP. I have been developing a PHP website code which requires a common header (header.php). I have included common header.php page in content.php. Now I see 2  2  and 2  tags in the HTML view source.

Code is something like this -

```
<?php
      include "header.php";

      //some php code.
?>
<html>
<head> <script src="test.js"> </script></head>
   <body>
        <h1> Test Page </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

In page source, my code looks like this,

```
<html>
<head> <script src="header.js"> </script></head>
   <body>
        <h1> Menu Page </h1>
   </body>
</html>
<html>
<head> <script src="test.js"> </script></head>
   <body>
        <h1> Test Page </h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Please suggest if this code is OK or multiple html or head tags are not good for SEO and/or performance. Also please suggest workaround.

Comment: Not OK.  Only one `<html>` tag per document.

Comment: Please suggest what can be done ?

Comment: Your HTML structure is broken. The browsers might be forgiving but the results will be unpredictable.

Comment: The work-around is for you to determine what in your PHP code is breaking your html and fix it.

Comment: Change the header.php file so it won't output any tags except maybe the head tag and it's contents.

Comment: @jasper, What can be done is use header.php as what it sounds like, a header. Put the header stuff like the `<HTML>` tag and JS/CSS references only in there.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question per se, but contrary to what many people are saying, a site can have multiple <html> tags. for example, YouTube has multiple <html> tags on its homepage. It's pretty common to do within an iframe, but I'm not sure if that's the only time one would. Take this with a grain of salt because I don't know much about this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can have only one `<HTML>` per page.

What you are looking for is a "layout pattern".

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

    <HEAD>
        <!-- your link to stylesheet, jquery etc -->
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <!-- here include your header -->

        <!-- and your content -->
    </BODY>

</HTML>
```

Both header and content don't have any `<HTML>` or the rest of it - it's just `<DIV>`'s etc.

If you are struggling with the basic HTML format, here are some **[basic html templates](http://www.ondrovo.com/article/template-html5)** you can use.

---

For any bigger application, it makes sense to use a framework (such as [**Laravel**](http://laravel.com/)) and some templating engine.

However, for this simple example, you could have something like this:

```
[file index.php]
- resolve what content to show based on $_GET
- include layout, tell it what title and content to show

[layout]
as shown above, add into <head> a <title> tag
in body, include the content files

[additional files for content, header etc]
...
```

Comment: +1 This means, OP would need an additional include.php, where scripts, styles and general HEAD options would be collected.

Comment: @ArtjomB. That really depends.. if those things are common, they can just be written in the layout. If you mean ie. `<title>`, well, then there would make sense to have one "master file" that includes layout,  and tells it what title and what content to show.

Comment: Where to put javascripts and css ? Header or Content.php page ?

Comment: @jasper See the examples I linked, there you have it all clearly shown. stylesheets go to head, scripts usually as well (but could be also in body).

Comment: Thank you very much MightyPork

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only have one set of

```
<html> </html>
```

tags

Answer (score 1):

A Html document contains exactly 1 HTML tag with a head and body tag inside it, by definition. So your code is not valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:

your `header.php` should contain the following html **ONLY**

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title></title>
     ....
   </head>
   <body>
```

Now your `body page` should contain only `divs` and content that goes within `<body></body>` only.

Then you have `footer.php` that ends the html like this:

```
   </body>
</html>
```

so in your main body file you would have the following:

```
<?php
   include "header.php";

   //some php code.
?>

<h1> Test Page </h1>

<?php
   include "footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use only one `<html><head><body>` and `<h1>` Tag to write valid html-code.

If you try to build a template like engine with php you could build it like that:

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="my.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

index.php

```
<?php
     include_once("header.php");
?>
<h1><?php echo $page_title; ?></h1>

<div class="main">
    <p>This is my Content</p>
</div>

<?php
    include_once("footer.php");
?>
```

footer.php

```
<script src="additional.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete html and body tag etc in header.php. That will solve your problem

Comment: And move the header include.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there are sometimes comment lines at the top of a html file that are used to configure the html for different browsers. If you run a script to strip the comment of something like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>  <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-GB"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

you will inadvertently end up with the appearance of 4 html loops which then causes a parser such as beautifulsoup to fail badly.